# Adding swipe gesture, Unable to swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Here i have three views one is the left,middle,right so i wanted to add the swipe functionality i have tried the following way but still unable to make it.How can i do this.

CODE :

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerRight:)];
        [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
        //Left Swipe

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer2 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerLeft:)];
        [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer2];

    }
```

Transition for right

```
    -(void)swipeHandlerRight:(id)sender
    {

         RightViewController *videoScreen=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RightViewController"];


CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFromRight;
   // transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [self presentViewController:videoScreen animated:NO completion:nil];


    }
```

Transition for Left

```
    -(void)swipeHandlerLeft:(id)sender
    {
        LeftViewController *videoScreen=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
         CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    // transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];


    }
```

Comment: what you want to achieve, i think you should use either page view controller or put 3 views in a scrollview with paging enabled. make the scrollview width as much as big you want as per your requirement.

Comment: Are those method not calling even a single time?

Comment: @NileshJha when i added a breakpoint and run the programme the view will appear get called and when i swipe left the breakpoint goes to the leftViewController and same for right but still the middle label is show up there, it should show left label when i swipe left as i added label on respective screens

Comment: Does you controller has `UINavigationController` as root view controller?

Comment: Virat check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:videoScreen animated:YES];
```

By this

```
[self presentViewController:videoScreen animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

It will make your view controller appear. But as the left or right view controller has no gesture Recognizer so you will not back from those view controller.For this you have make them like to swipe.

Comment: ya this is working but i wanted the animation like it should show up according to swipe but it is presenting the left viewController from the bottom but it should come from left

Comment: @virat did you added UINavigationControl‌​ler or not?

Comment: @iRaju  no i did not add

Comment: Add from storyboard in root view controller

Comment: @SMi ya it is working now but i wanted to get back to middle view from right how to come back from the right to middle.

Comment: @virat why you are not using pageviewcontroller or page control?

Comment: because i did not know this stuff before first time i am working on swipe functionality.

Comment: Actually how you want now will be tough to manage in future. In this case it is better to go with iOS default features. You may follow this https://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution brother.I tried sample project for your question.Now I got the solution.

First I set the ViewControllers in storyboard.See the storyboard which have UINavigationController,ViewController,LeftViewController,RightViewController in below screenshot.

[image]

Then in ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RightViewController.h"
#import "LeftViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  //swipe right
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerRight:)];
  [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

  //swipe left
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer2 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerLeft:)];
  [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer2];

}

#pragma mark - swipe right function
-(void)swipeHandlerRight:(id)sender
{
   RightViewController *videoScreen=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RightViewController"];

   CATransition *animationRight = [CATransition animation];
   [animationRight setDuration:0];
   [animationRight setType:kCATransitionFromRight];
   [animationRight setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
   [animationRight setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
   [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:animationRight forKey:kCATransition];
   [self presentViewController:videoScreen animated:NO completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - swipe left function
-(void)swipeHandlerLeft:(id)sender
{
   LeftViewController *videoScreen=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
   CATransition *animationLeft = [CATransition animation];
   [animationLeft setDuration:0];
   [animationLeft setType:kCATransitionFromLeft];
   [animationLeft setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
   [animationLeft setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
   [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:animationLeft forKey:kCATransition];
   [self presentViewController:videoScreen animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

RightViewController.m

```
#import "RightViewController.h"

@interface RightViewController ()

@end

@implementation RightViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Back to MiddleView
- (IBAction)actionBackToMiddleView:(id)sender
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

LeftViewController.m

```
#import "LeftViewController.h"

@interface LeftViewController ()

@end

@implementation LeftViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Back to MiddleView
- (IBAction)actionBackToMiddleViewFromLeftView:(id)sender
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```